# ElasticSearch VS Postgresql VS Kafka/ksql

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I am using elasticsearch as primary database.
But due to the lack of the ACID properties, I want to:

- or replace it with another database with similar or better performances ( maybe postgresql or kafka/ksql ).
- or use other solution together with elasticsearch to avoid the loss of data ( due to the lack of the ACID properties ).

So what is the better solution? and how can I check what are the performance differences between ElasticSearch and the other solution?

Comment: Can you edit your question to be clearer on (a) *what* are you trying to do - what are you project requirements (rather than *how*, i.e. tool choice) and (b) *why* are you looking to Kafka/ksqlDB? You also need to be specific with your question otherwise it'll probably get closed as opinion-based.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt Done. Is it more clear? Thanks :)

Comment: What is it that you're using Elasticsearch for? Which of the absent ACID properties are causing you trouble? Elasticsearch, Postgres, and Kafka are all very different beasts - each with very strong characteristics in their particular domain. It really depends on your specific requirements, which you've not really spelt out in your question.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt The ACID properties that are causing me trouble is the loss of data. My requirements are speed in searching, distribution, resilience and high availability.

Comment: These solutions aren't exclusive. You can use transactional Kafka producers plus Kafka Connect/KSQL to sink data to Elasticsearch (**and** Pinot, Druid, Postgres, etc) for searching. Kafka is not a database, though